# How to read text image from pdf using pdfbox

Tags: c#, .net, pdfbox

I have one PDF document with image. That image contains text.
Now I want to read the text from the image using pdfbox.

I have tried the PDTTextStripper but it not working for image text.
Can you please give some idea about it.

```
PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new java.io.File(fileName));
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
string text = textStripper.getText(pDDocument);
Console.WriteLine(text);

I want to read the text inside the image from the pdf using pdfbox c# .net.
```

Comment: PDFBox can *extract* text from a PDF, i.e. decoded string parameters of text drawing instructions in the PDF. It cannot *recognize* text in images. What you need is an OCR solution. PDFBox can be used to extract bitmap images or render pages as bitmap images.

Comment: Get the source code of ExtractImages to get these images that you want to OCR. Alternatively convert the whole page to an image.